# Wierd Xamarin/Mono/CLR runtime fault? KeyNotFoundException thrown when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

[image: This exception should not happen]

Hi there. I am currently working on a Xamarin/Android application and notice the behaviour outlined in the image at runtime. I don't know why this is happening, but when conditionals that should be true are resolving as false - then the application clearly isn't doing what you are telling it to do! Which is a major problem to have as programmer.

```
public class DataProvider
{
    private readonly DeviceModelFactory factory;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DeviceModel> deviceCache;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DeviceSetup> setupCache;

    public DataProvider()
    {
        this.factory = new DeviceModelFactory();
        this.deviceCache = new Dictionary<string, DeviceModel>();
        this.setupCache = new Dictionary<string, DeviceSetup>();
    }

    public DeviceSetup GetDeviceSetupByDataNode(DataNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
        }

        var fullPath = node.Path;

        lock (this.setupCache)
        {
            if (!this.setupCache.ContainsKey(fullPath))
            {
                this.setupCache.Add(fullPath, this.factory.GetDeviceSetupByDataNode(node));
                this.setupCache[fullPath].SetDataNode(node);
            }
        }

        return this.setupCache[fullPath];
    }

    public DeviceModel GetDeviceModelByDataNode(DataNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
        }

        var key = node.Path;

        lock (this.deviceCache)
        {
            if (!this.deviceCache.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                this.deviceCache.Add(key, this.factory.GetDeviceModelByDataNode(node));
                this.deviceCache[key].SetDataNode(node);
            }

            try
            {
                return this.deviceCache[key];
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debugger.Break(); // How the f**k is this happening?!
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Device cache missing entry for key : {key}");
            }
        }
    }

    public void ClearSetupCache()
    {
        lock (this.setupCache)
        {
            this.setupCache.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void ClearDeviceCache()
    {
        lock (this.deviceCache)
        {
            this.deviceCache.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

An exception is getting thrown when attempting to return the entry from the dictionary for the key. However, as you see prior to the lookup, it will add the key if no entry exists. It appears as though the if statement is resolving as false, even though the condition passed into it is true.

The application then attempts to get the entry at for the specified key, but will then throw a KeyNotFoundException because it simply doesn't exist (although, in such cases it SHOULD be added prior to retrieval).

The only thing I can think of is that the mono framework that this Xamarin application is built upon is at fault.

Have any of you experienced this behaviour? Are there any resolutions in place?

Comment: What exception is being thrown there? You're catching `Exception` -- is `ex` definitely a `KeyNotFoundException`?

Comment: It's probably a threading issue? I notice you've got a lock around the dictionary access, suggesting that multiple threads are involved. Are all other access to the dictionary protected by the same lock? Is the dictionary ever re-assigned? Can you share the code for that whole class?

Comment: Also, don't post images of text. Please post your code as actual text, in your question

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: "It's probably a threading issue? "

There are other threads in the application, but none which clear or interact with the dictionary other than to read from it. I put a lock around anyway, just in case.

Comment: Can you post the entire class, including all places which interact with that dictionary in any way

Comment: I wouldn't lock the cache dictionary itself instead create another Object _lockObject and lock that and change the dictionary.

Comment: Sure. I thought lock() sinply needed an object reference to apply the block against. Why use a seperate object from the object you wish to block access on? The variable that the lock is held against is a readonly field instantiated in the providers .ctor

Answer (score 0):

Developer error : The build I was debugging didn't actually have the lock around dictionary where the ClearSetupCache() and the ClearDeviceCache() methods were being called.

Comment: Accept your answer to close the question.